# SQL: Using Stored Procedure within a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, truncate

I have a few stored procedures that return the same set of data (same columns) to a user.  The stored procedure called depends on certain conditions.  These stored procedures are fairly intensive and are being run by every user of the system.  I would like to create stored procedure that calls each of these procedures and stores the data on a separate table.  I will then run this new stored procedure every 5 minutes or so and let the users pull from the new table.

T_OutboundCallList is a permanent table with the same columns as returned by the two stored procedures.

I would like something like the following but when I try to run this it just runs continuously and I have to stop the procedure.

```
BEGIN

TRUNCATE TABLE T_OutboundCallList


INSERT T_OutboundCallList EXECUTE p_LeadVendor_GetCallsForCallList

INSERT T_OutboundCallList EXECUTE p_CallLog_GetAbandonedCallsCallList

END
```

Each of the procedures (*CallList) return a list of calls to be made and I do want them entered into the new table in this order (LeadVendor calls before AbandonedCalls).  I also need to clear the table before adding the calls as there may be new calls that need to be higher in the list.

Is there some problem with this procedure that I am not seeing?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code in your *CallList procs it is hard to say what issue you are having. You should have the insert commands inside of your nested procedure. You can use the results of a procedure to insert data, but not like you are above. It is using `OPENROWSET`, and I think you will be better off the way I suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I rewrote my stored procedures to do the insert within each of the nested stored procedures which works great.